# How do you work using an outlook business network to send an email with the domain of the same company?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am in a company where we have a firewall, proxy and a domain, our email is like this: persona@company.co, we use outlook exchange.

I try to send an email but it gives me an authentication error, I don't know if the firewall blocking it or proxy.

I want to send an email using the phpmailer library among those who have Exchange accounts within our corporate network

My code:

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer.php';
require 'SMTP.php';

// Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                      // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.office365.com';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'me@business.co';                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = '*********';                               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` also accepted
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('email@from.com', 'Angel');
    $mail->addAddress('******@business.co');     // Add a recipient

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

Debug output:

[image]

Comment: There's not enough info here. Please set `SMTPDebug = 2` and add the output to your question.

Comment: Info here:

2020-01-08 11:55:22 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (10060)
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: That's a timeout, not an authentication failure. Your ISP probably blocks outbound SMTP. Diagnose that using the advice in the troubleshooting guide the error message points you at.

Comment: Okay

I want to try my personal outlook account to find out more. Start on it to send an email

The SMTP is: smtp.office365.com
Port: 587
SMTPSecure: STARTTLS

Yes?

Comment: That looks ok; It probably took you longer to type that than to try it!

Comment: Yes XD, with my personal outlook account it worked, but using my business account it didn't.

Comment: Info debug here: https://ibb.co/bRv8SY0   like a img because the string too long

Comment: OK, so that simply looks like either your credentials are wrong, or your account is not configured to allow SMTP sending using those credentials - so probably nothing to do with your script, everything to do with your outlook account.

Comment: Ah ok I understand, hey and how can I know which is the SMTP of the company, because they have their own domain, proxy and firewall as I had told you. I have looked in the outlook application to see if I found the SMPT of the company that configures my email. You understand me?

Comment: Outlook is a reasonable place to look if you've got a known-working config in there. Be aware that SMTP and proxies don't get on that well, rarely used for outbound mail.

Comment: Ok, thanks for all the information